# How to hide UITabBar Selection style?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

In my app,I have a UITabBar.I want to hide/remove that tabbar item selection style ie.,that glossy effect.Is it possible to do it programmatically?..Also is there any way to position the tab bar items programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be helped you.....

```
// iOS 5.0+
[self.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[[UIImage alloc] init]autorelease]];


// for earlier versions

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self customizeTabBar];
}

- (void)customizeTabBar {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tabBackground%i.png", tabBarCtrl.selectedIndex + 1];

    for(UIView *view in tabBarCtrl.tabBar.subviews) {  
         if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {  
              [view removeFromSuperview];  
         }  
    }  
    UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]] autorelease];
    [tabBarCtrl.tabBar insertSubview:background atIndex:0]; 
    [tabBarCtrl.tabBar bringSubviewToFront:background];
    //if needed, here must be adding UILabels with titles, I didn't need it.
}
```